# MapStruct : Converting Map(Key, Value) where Value is a CSV to a Set<String>

Tags: collections, hashmap, set, mapstruct

My HashMap looks like this
`{"Key1" : "1, 2, 3, 4"}`

I need to convert this using Mapstruct and get it mapped on my Model Object as

```java
Set<<MapValue>> myvalues;
```

and should print like

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Can you pls assist

Answer (score 0):

Such complex mappings are outside of the MapStruct project.

In order to achieve what you are looking for you'll need to provide a custom mapping for your specific use case.